# Neo4j : variable length relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

There are nodes with label **:Feature** and between the feature nodes there is a relationship called **parent_of**.

So, some features are child features and some are parent features. Child feature of one feature might be the parent of other feature.

**Required Cypher** : Cypher which takes input as a feature no. and returns output as: what is it's parent feature and the features connected to that parent feature  and again the child and parent feature connected to those features (this goes on till the leaf node).

Below is a screenshot of the relationship:

[Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGyna.png)

[Example graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBF80.png)

Comment: So it sounds like, given a feature no., you want the entire connected graph of :Feature nodes connected by :parent_of relationships? Your description didn't seem to specify going only in one direction or the other (just parents of the :Feature, or just children).

Comment: Also a more concrete example image would be helpful, showing on the full graph the starting node and all the nodes you want the query to return.

Comment: @InverseFalcon suppose for an e.g. given feature no. is 123 and 123 has a parent feature no.1234 and this 1234 feature no. can be the child of other feature no. (e.g. 12345)...so it goes on till the hierarchy exists...so i want 123 to be printed along with 1234 as parent feature of 123 and also 12345 that 1234's parent is 12345 and so on....

Comment: @InverseFalcon thanks for your suggestion. I have uploaded an image(link in starting of the question). So, if i give 123 feature no. as input, whole network should come up and it should stop only if further parent_of relationship does't exist. And how can I present the graph output to the outer world so that they would be able to understand that what graph depicts

Comment: Thanks for the example graph. Am I correct that you would want feature with number 12345678 in the result set, even if it's the child of 123456, rather than a parent of an ancestor of 123? If so, would you want the results to also include parents and children of 12345678 if there were any present (and continuing to all other connected nodes)?

Comment: @InverseFalcon yes you are correct i want a main parent connected to 123 for e.g 1234 in the example graph plus i want all data connected to 1234 and goes on till 12345678. Yes, I want the results to include parents and children of 12345678 if they are present. So in brief I should be able to present that 1234 is the parent of 123 but 1234 is the child of 12345 and 12345 is the child of 123456 and goes on till where the network exists.

Answer (score 0):

I think the path expander procedures from [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) may help here.

If you only need the connected nodes, then use `apoc.path.subgraphNodes()`. If you want paths, then use `apoc.path.spanningTree()`.

As far as outputting data in a format that captures the relational information between the nodes, you could either output relationships (along with each relationship's start and end nodes), which will involve some duplication of output data, or maybe you could use an APOC Procedure to transform a collection of paths to a nested JSON tree?

One example:

```
MATCH (f:Feature{feature_no:$startNo})
CALL apoc.path.spanningTree(f, {relationshipFilter:'parent_of', labelFilter:'>Feature'}) YIELD path
WITH collect(path) as paths
CALL apoc.convert.toTree(paths) YIELD value
RETURN value
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @InverseFalcon. But if I want data in the form of graph like I attached in the above image "Example graph", what needs to be done. Could you also help how to write Cypher query using apoc.path.subgraphNodes() which meets the requirements. Thank you

Comment: So you're only interested in the graphical result, not the row results?

Comment: Thanks@Inverse.I want row only, which I'm getting perfectly through the above query but want to consume data in JSON format. But relationship direction is missing in JSON due to which unable to find  that whether the output features are the parent or child of the given feature.For ex:if a feature no. has an outgoing relship of :parent_of and incoming relship of :parent_of(means if a given feature has one child and one parent), so query is unable to find which is the parent and child of given feature as it gives the same relationship :parent_of ,it doesn't take into account the direction inJSON